# Diagonalizing a matrix question on determinant property

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, diagonalization

So the equation I am used to is $\det(A - \lambda I )x = 0$ when trying to find the eigenspace, but I have seen some people solve for the eigenspace doing $\det(\lambda I - A )$ and was wondering is there a theorem stating that the $\det(A - B) = \det(B - A)$.

Comment: Closely, $\det (-A)= (-1)^n \det A$ where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Although I don't think this is enough for you to compute.

Comment: The advantage of $\det(\lambda I- A)$ is that you always get a monic polynomia. The advantage of $\det(A-\lambda I)$ is that writing $A-\lambda I$ does not involve any sign changes, and so is less prone to error when doing by hand, and is easier to do mentally for small matrices.

Answer (score 3):

In general,

$$\det(-E)=(-1)^n \det(E)$$

where $n$ is the size of the matrix $E$. So $\det(A-B)=(-1)^n\det(B-A)$. Therefore:

$$
\det(\lambda I-A)=0 \iff \det(A-\lambda I)=0
$$
which is what you wanted.